# How to identity which php framework is used from code or folder structure?

Tags: php, frameworks

I have got a php project with me to make some modification in the system.
The code seems to be in MVC pattern. So its definitely developed using some php framework.

The top level folders are application, common, system & cgi-bin.

I am new to php frameworks, to make changes in code I need to know the framework used.

Can anyone help me to identify framework ?

Comment: can you check what is in system folder?

Comment: looks like the expression engine folder structure, but I could be wrong.

Comment: It should be most obvious by looking at the main index.php file from the publicly accessible folder.

Comment: @suraj In system folder there are php files -> **config, controller, model, session, validate, view, request, functions**. Also a **classes** folder